# reformatting a json file (python)

Tags: python, json

I have a json file which is split into 3 sections..

```
{
"columns": {
"0": "Account Number",
"1": "Airport",
"2": "Terminal",
},
"rows": [
[
[
{
"v": "1234 "
},
{
"v": "LHR - London Heathrow"
},
{
"v": "T3"
}
]
]
]
,"types": [
    {
        "0": "TEXT",
        "1": "TEXT",
        "2": "TEXT"
}
]
}
```

what i want it to be like is this :

{
"Account Number" : "1234",
"Airport" : "LHR - London Heathrow",
"Terminal" : "T3"
}

How can acheive this please?

Comment: If you're asking how to access data in a dictionary/list you should do more research. Otherwise, your question is unclear.

Comment: no it was not unclear..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependencies

```
import json
import ast
```

Reading Json as file

```
with open("file.json") as f:
    data = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

Reading Json as String

```
askersString = """{
"columns": {
"0": "Account Number",
"1": "Airport",
"2": "Terminal",
},
"rows": [
[
[
{
"v": "1234 "
},
{
"v": "LHR - London Heathrow"
},
{
"v": "T3"
}
]
]
]
,"types": [
    {
        "0": "TEXT",
        "1": "TEXT",
        "2": "TEXT"
}
]
}"""

data = ast.literal_eval(askersString)
```

Creating new json

```
columns = data["columns"]
a = data["rows"][0][0]
newJson = {}

for k, v in columns.items():
    newJson[v] = a[int(k)]['v']

updatedJson = json.dumps(newJson, indent=4)
print(updatedJson)
```

Output

```
{
    "Account Number": "1234 ",
    "Airport": "LHR - London Heathrow",
    "Terminal": "T3"
}
```

Comment: Probably use `json.loads` and `json.dumps` as part of the solution?

Comment: everything nice so far, but you should extract the values of the JSON `columns` dynamically, and then use within the newly generated JSON.

Comment: it says `Json ^as String
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks @BarbarosÖzhan I put `"Json as String"` as placeholder but now i added literal json

Comment: i am getting an error with this line :
columns = data["columns"]
the error is : "string indices must be integers" ..
what is that about?

Comment: need more help please??

Comment: Sorry @MrPaul i just saw your comment you saw that error because data variable is not list that's dictionary we create dictionary in `ast.literal_eval` method